# retrieve multiple file based stored images from postgres database using python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I want to retrieve images stored in data tables using python jupyter notebook and save them in desktop folder but unable to understand where  I'm doing mistake.

```
def write_file(data, filename):
# Convert binary data to proper format and write it on Hard Disk
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data)


cursor.execute("SELECT * from mydb where id = {0}")
record = cursor.fetchall()
for row in record:
    ID= row[0]
    print("Id = ", row[0])
    image =  row[1]
    photo= r"C:\Users\my_profile\Desktop\outputimage\img{0}.JPG".format(str(ID))
    write_file(image, photo)
```

Comment: No problem seems. Are you sure the first column is `ID`, and the second is `yourBlob`  for asterisk notation of the SELECT statement? I mean that you have a look at the table creation DDL for columns order.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was making minor mistake that has been solved now.

Comment: you're welcome Ayshe